# Writing a parametric equation in $y=f(x)$ form

Tags: parametric

I have two equations  in  $x$ and $y$ in terms of some parameter $t$ as under
$$ x(t)=-a.sin(at)-a\  \text{and}\\ y(t)=a.cos(at) .$$
Is it possible to eliminate t and find the relation between $x$ and $y$ in $y=f(x)$ or $f(x,y)=0$?Are there some general methods to achieve that end.Thank you in adavance for your responces and comments.

Comment: Hint. Use the fact $\sin(at)^2+\cos(at)^2=1$

Comment: It is not possible to have $y=f(x)$ for these, since the points $(x(t), y(t))$ on the parametrized curve are not "right unique". For example, $(-a, a)$ and $(-a,-a)$ are both on the curve. It is possible to solve for $y=f(x)$ on some segments of the curve, restricting $c\le t \le d$ so that all points on that segment are right unique.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x(t)=(-a\sin(at)-a)
\\
\text{and}
\\
y(t)=a\cos(at).
$$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
x(t)=-a\sin(at)-a,\\
y(t)=a\cos(at).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1=\sin(at),\\
\frac{y(t)}{a}=\cos(at).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{\arcsin\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)}{a},\\
\frac{y(t)}{a}=\cos(at).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{\arcsin\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)}{a},\\
\frac{y(t)}{a}=\cos({\arcsin\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)}).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{\arcsin\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)}{a},\\
\frac{y(t)}{a}=\left(1-\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)^{2}\right)^{0.5}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{\arcsin\left(-\frac{x(t)}{a}-1\right)}{a},\\
{y}=a\left(\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{2x}{a}\right)^{0.5}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
So we get that
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
{y}=a\left(\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{2x}{a}\right)^{0.5}.
}
$$
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the transcendental nature of equations $a$ cannot be eliminated resulting into elementary functions. We use numerical methods to find such solutions. E.g., Newton-Raphson, Regula Falsi etc.

Using identity $ \sin ^2 at + \cos^2 at =1 $ we obtain the eliminant Circle without a need to carry out such an elimination.

$$ \frac{(x+a)^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$$

[image]